# What are analogs of "#ifdef", "#ifndef", "#else", "#elif", "#define", "#undef" in D programming language?

Tags: preprocessor, d

In C/C++ we have preprocessor directives (see title of the question). What is the analog of them in D language?
And how to detect operating system type (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, ...) and processor type (e.g.: 32 or 64 bits) at compile-time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** The best answer is already on dlang.org: http://dlang.org/pretod.html .

D has no preprocessor. Instead it gives powerful compile-time evaluation and introspection capabilities.

Here is a simple list of typical C/C++ to D translations, with links to relevant documents:

---

**C/C++**: `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#else`, `#elif`

**D**: `version` [[link](http://dlang.org/version.html)]

---

**C/C++**: `#if <condition>`

**D**: `static if` [[link](http://dlang.org/version.html#staticif)]

---

**C/C++**: `#define`

**D**: D translation depends on the case.

Simple C/C++ define like `#define FOO` is translated to D's "[version](http://dlang.org/version.html)". Example: `version = FOO`

Code like `#define BAR 40` is translated to the following D code: `enum BAR 40` or in rare cases you may need to use the `alias`.

Complex *defines* like `#define GT_CONSTRUCT(depth,scheme,size) \
    ((depth) | (scheme) | ((size) << GT_SIZE_SHIFT))` are translated into D's templates:

```
// Template that constructs a graphtype
template GT_CONSTRUCT(uint depth, uint scheme, uint size) {
  // notice the name of the const is the same as that of the template
  const uint GT_CONSTRUCT = (depth | scheme | (size << GT_SIZE_SHIFT));
}
```

([Example taken from the D wiki](http://wiki.dlang.org/Converting_C_.h_Files_to_D_Modules))

---

**C/C++**: `#undef`

**D**: There is no adequate translation that I know of

Comment: what about `#if defined(X)`?

Answer (score 8):

`#if condition` is replaced by `static if(condition)` (with much more compile time evaluation)

`#ifdef ident` is replaced by `version(ident)`

`#define ident` is replaced by `version = ident`

`#define ident replacement` is replaced by `alias ident replacement`

more information at http://dlang.org/version.html and a list of [predefined version defines](http://dlang.org/version.html#PredefinedVersions)

Answer (score 3):

This could be of some use regarding preprocessor directives in C vs D:
http://dlang.org/pretod.html

Regarding the detection of OS and processor type, this thread looks like it might answer your questions: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/mailman.616.1387191250.3242.digitalmars-d-learn@puremagic.com?page=1

Note: I am familiar with C/C++ but not D. If my answer is insufficient, let me know so I can change it. Hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Analog ifndef.
Here is testing for symbol existens:

If `FT_THROW` not defined, then define default function FT_THROW. This is analog common code with ifndef.

```
import std.stdio;

// my implementation of FT_THROW
void FT_THROW( int x ) { writeln( "calling redefined FT_THROW(): ", x*x ); }

// ifndef FT_THROW
static if ( !is( typeof( FT_THROW ) ) )
{
    pragma( msg, "FT_THROW not exists. using default implementation." );

    // default implementation of FT_THROW
    void FT_THROW( int x ) { writeln( "call FT_THROW(): ", x ); }
}


void main()
{
    // ifdef FT_THROW
    static if ( is( typeof( FT_THROW ) ) )  // checking for FT_THROW extsts
    {
        pragma( msg, "FT_THROW found" );
    }

    FT_THROW( 7 );
}
```

Online: https://run.dlang.io/is/N3ENqb

Real example:

```
#ifndef FT_MEM_ZERO
#define FT_MEM_ZERO( dest, count )  FT_MEM_SET( dest, 0, count )
#endif
```

is

```
static if ( !is( typeof( FT_MEM_ZERO ) ) ) 
{
    auto FT_MEM_ZERO( T1, T2 )( T1 dest, T2 count )  { FT_MEM_SET( dest, 0, count ); }
}
```

Example 2:

```
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE   1
#endif
```

is

```
static if ( !is( typeof( TRUE ) ) ) 
    enum TRUE = 1;
```